How to export .dim file (from SNAP) to TIFF via gpt (command line)
I've downloaded Sentinel-1 data from the Dataspace ecosystem and applied some pre-processing steps using Python. After cropping and pre-processing, I saved the output as a .dim file (called updated_output_v8) - see the second image in SNAP. I have created a model (.xml) with the steps that are depicted below (see the first image).


I want to export two specific bands, Sigma0_VH and Sigma0_VV, as GeoTIFF files. I tried the following command. My current directory is where gpt is located F:\SNAP\bin\gpt
gpt Write -Pfile=F:\ilias\Sentinel_1\outputs_v4\updated_output_v8.dim -f GeoTIFF -t F:\ilias\Sentinel_1\outputs_v4\final_output_2024-09-18.tif

I got the following error [output] is Null. What am I missing?
P.S.: I know that I can find the images (.img) in the folder updated_output_v8.data which was created when the model was executed.

